# How to check if an array is in a list of array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I've read an answer about the same question but it use id() and doesn't seems to work.

I try to do with 'b in res', b being an array and res an array list but the outcome is this error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

the error and the code line

[image: the error and the code line]

Comment: Could you also put your code here?

Comment: Do you mean numpy arrays?

Comment: Can you please paste your [mcve] and the full traceback instead of screenshots?

Comment: If `b` is a list and `res` is a list of lists, then `b in res` works as expected. Or are you referring to `np.array`? There's no such thing as `arraylist` on Python.